# Suction base cups removal

Tags: bathroom

I have sited a Gecko loc caddy wrongly. What's the best way to remove the base plate from the tiled wall without damage.

Answer (score 1):

According to the web page, the [Gecko-loc](http://gecko-loc.com/) uses silicone rubber suction cups which are held in place by turning the knob, ostensibly pulling a vacuum on the inside of the cup. It describes the removal as simple as peeling it off. That's the only reference I found.

[image: gecko-loc hanger]

One would therefore believe that you would remove the hanging device from the cup and turn the knob in the opposite direction to release the vacuum.

I've also noted that the company offers a 3M VHB tape option. 3M VHB tape is not so easily removed. One method of removal, if you have used that option, is to carefully slice with a razor or equally thin sharp cutting device between the wall and the cup mount. Once the body of the adhesive is split, additional scraping and application of adhesive removal product such as Goo-Gone will eliminate the residue. The web site provides for replacement adhesive panels.

Ideally, you have the suction cup design. Pop off the caddy, turn the knobs and re-locate.

Comment: I used a thin wire instead of a razor... attached to two bits of wood.